# Последовательность выполнения ф-ций в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Что-то я никак не могу разобраться как реализовать последовательность выполнения ф-ций в jQuery?
Т.е. например имеем

```
<div id="div1">Я див</div>
```

И при первом клике на него задаем ему border:1px solid red.
А при втором клике делаем бордер черный...

как я себе это примерно представляю:

```
$('#div1').live('click',function(){
  $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
}).live('click',function(){
  $(this).css('border','1px solid black');
});
```

Но такой вариант не работает, при первом же клике сразу присваивается border BLACK

Кто-то в курсе как правильно сделать?

Comment: Я бы решил это через доп. переменную. И повесил бы на див только клик. А в нём менял бы значение этой переменной и в зависимости от него делал бы разные действия.

Comment: Немного не понял вас.
Вообще я для примера указал такие действия.

Мне же на самом деле нужно при первом клике выводить бордер, а при втором выполнять ajax запрос.

С вашими "дополнительными переменными" это можно будет сделать?

Comment: Нужен флаг, который бы дал знать функции, что по диву уже кликали и у него бордер блэк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При первом клике добавляете какой-нибуть класс к объекту и при повторном клике ориентируетесь уже на него
[Смотрим пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/74pk8/)

```
$('#div1').live('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ups')){
        $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('border','1px solid black').addClass('ups');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо!  
Обожаю этот сайт :)